# Suma y agrupar con laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo  una tabla de sales

```
[

  { 
    "sale_number":37,
    "sale_token":"KTVUX8Q9DQ",      
    "created_by":"ManuelMorales",
    "status":"pending",,
    "price":20,
  },


  {
   "sale_number":38,
   "sale_token":"KTVUX8Q9DQ",
   "created_by":"Manuel Morales",
   "status":"pending",
   "price":20,
 }
```

]

Lo que quiero es  sumar el price y agrupar por el sale_toque y retornar algo asi.

```
 [

   {
     'Manuel moralez'
   },

   {
     'price':40
   }
 ]
```

Como pude hacerlo ?
eh intentado con lo metedo que ay aquí pero no obtengo el resultado que quiero 
esta es mi consulta

```
 public function show(Sale $sale)
  {
     $ticket = DB::table('sales')
        ->select(DB::raw('sale_token,SUM(price) as price'))
        ->where('status', 'pending')
        ->groupBy('sale_token')->pluck('sale_token', 'price');
    return response()->json($ticket, 200);

  }
```

Comment: La consulta que nos muestras que resultado te da?

Comment: este es el resutado {"40":"KTVUX8Q9DQ"}

Comment: ¿Y si en vez de  `pluck()` usas `get()` qué te devuelve?

Comment: porloscerros muchas gracias cambiando pluck por get si obtengo el resultado que quería

Comment: de igual manera puedes usar SelectRaw